# Qual a diferença entre as versões do Xamarin?

Tags: terminologia, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-forms, xamarin.ios

Qual a diferença entre as versões ***Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.iOS e Xamarin.Android***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviamente Xamarin.iOS e Xamarin.Android são implementações do Xamarin para estas plataformas específicas e acessam 100% da API da plataforma (pelo menos tenta sempre estar por volta disto). Obviamente com alguma adaptação para se conformar com a filosofia do C#, mas acessa a API direto. Note que a diferença fica basicamente na UI e acesso específico às funcionalidades, mas boa parte do código pode ser aproveitado. Programar com eles é quase como se estivesse programando com Java ou Swift, mas é C#.

Xamarin.Forms é uma abstração que permite aproveitar próximo a 100% do seu código, incluindo UI aproveitada para as duas plataformas. É uma camada que adota uma estratégia que funciona bem em uma plataforma e razoável e outra. Economiza horas de desenvolvimento e manutenção, aprendizado de plataformas diferentes e evita duplicação de código, mas não tem a melhor UX possível. Ele permite uso com Windows Phone e Desktop (Windows 10) também.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

**Xamarin.Forms** é um framework multiplataforma (*Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone*) para criação de aplicações com XAML ou C#, que unifica a escrita de interfaces de usuário para cada plataforma.

Portanto, quando eu construo um aplicativo na plataforma Xamarin, utilizando o framework Xamarin.Forms, vou ter a possibilidade de compartilhar o meu código do "core" e as minhas interfaces de usuário, seja ela Windows, Android, iOS, etc.

A Plataforma Xamarin entrega duas alternativas para construção de aplicativos moveis, **Xamarin.iOS** `(permite desenvolvimento de aplicações para iOS usando controles de interface desenvolvidos com Objective-C/Xcode)` e **Xamarin.Android** `(permite desenvolvimento de aplicações para Android usando controles de interface desenvolvidos com Java)`, onde você tem acesso direto as API’s de cada plataforma enquanto Xamarin.Forms tem como foco maximizar o compartilhamento ([Portable Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/)) de código entre essas plataformas.

Exemplo: A implementação de um botão é diferente entre as plataformas, quando decido usar Xamarin.Forms ele unifica o comportamento, resolve e apresenta esse botão em cada plataforma respeitando as suas características.

Xamarin.iOS e/ou Xamarin.Android é normalmente utilizado em cenários onde:

- Aplicações requerem interações especializadas;
- Apps onde UI personalizada é mais importante do que o compartilhamento de código.

Já Xamarin.Forms é normalmente utilizado quando:

- O aplicativo exige poucas funcionalidades especificas para cada plataforma;
- Apps onde compartilhar código entre plataforma é mais importante do que a interface do usuário personalizada.