# Xamarin Portable

Tags: .net, xamarin

É possivel no Xamarin, ter um projeto Xamarin.Android e Xamarion.IOS e ter uma classe classe que acessa o SQLite e reutilizar ela nesses dois projetos?

Como podemos chamar isso?

Alguem tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Sim, é possível, acho que isto está respondido em algumas dessas perguntas ou no conjunto delas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192117/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38099/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186582/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127567/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128446/101

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível.

Hoje existem duas formas de realizar o compartilhamento de código no Xamarin.

**Projetos Portable(Será substituido por .NET Standard) e Shared (SAP).**

Para seu cenário, acesso ao SQLite, nos projetos iOS e Android voce precisará utilizar os conceitos, Partial Class para projetos do tipo SAP ou Injeção de dependencia para projetos Portable, isto fica a sua preferencia, sendo necessário realizar pequenas implementações para cada plataforma.

**Porque é necessário ter implementações para cada plataforma?**

Cada plataforma armazena o arquivo SQLite em Paths diferentes, sendo necessário sua implementação em cada plataforma, portanto, utilizando estes padroes podemos compartilhar todo o código comum e implementar em cada plataforma o que é especifico.

De uma pesquisada que voce verá implementações e utilização destes cenários, inclusive possui uma maratona Xamarin que fala sobre estes tópicos SQLite e Compartilhamentos de código via Xamarin.

Comment: Onde tem essa maratona?

Comment: @BiaBaldasso, segue o link com informacoes. http://ticapacitacion.com/curso/xamarinpt/

Comment: "Será substituido por .NET Standard" - quando ira ocorrer?